# Plugin slide that moves only in one direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slide

I need a plugin that moves the images in only one direction. Even when its the last slide, it returns to the first without changing the direction, always from right to left. I was using unslider.js but even changing the default settings, didn't get what i need. This is what I need:
[Example](http://letras.mus.br/). Does anyone know something like this? It would REALLY help me. Thank you guys.

Comment: I tried this: $(document).ready(function () {
 var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();
$('.unslider-arrow').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
      unslider.data('unslider')['next']();  
    } else {
      unslider.data('unslider')['next']();  
    };
});

});

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned unslider.js, have you tried something like that?

```
var sldr = $('.banner').unslider(),
    data = sldr.data('unslider');
data.prev = function() {
    // prev direction disabled
};
```

Comment: but i don't need to disable the prev, i just need to change the direction that the slide moves... :/